# my listview doesn't fill parent

Tags: java, android, listview, scrollview

> ```
> <RelativeLayout 
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
>     <TextView 
>         android:id="@+id/tv_test"
>         android:text="Test "
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     />
>     <ListView 
>         android:id="@+id/list_test"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_below="@id/tv_test"
>
>   ></ListView>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

And everything is in a ScrollView, i don't know why but the relative layout seems to set a wrap content. And it makes the ListView small and not taking the whole place.

I don't know if it's useful but here's my java code :

```
public class ShowView extends Activity{
ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] myList = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Height", "Nine", "Ten"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_test);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Comment: Could you please show whole xml code?

Comment: It's working fine buddy I checked your code and executed.

Comment: Maybe somewhere in your xml you have wrap_content instead of fill_parent. So if you send all your xml code I'll be able to help

Comment: It okay it's working, but what i wanted to do next was : make the listview work with the ScrollView. Look for the IMDB Android app, because they did a scrollview and you can see that inside there are listviews and it doesn't look like lists.

Comment: If you have only textview and listview then I think you dont need to use scroll view just use listview and add header or footer any view to it.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is i wanted to test it before, that's why i just put a single textview. But in my real app there will be more on top.

Comment: and what about if you create a xml file for the top layout(put in it as many component as you want) then inflate it as listview's header? Try it. And if worked then please inform me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you ScrollView is not filling the entire screen. Use this inside scrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: Okay thanks it was the solution, but i've got a little thing i wanted to do : Scroll everything in the layout, like it's all a same screen.

Comment: This is a good fix. As a note I had to add this value in both the ScrollView and the ListView that it contained. In android studio 0.9.9  there is a UI checkbox option to enable this directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 8):

Replace the `RelativeLayout` with a vertical `LinearLayout`, and set `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on your ListView:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_test"
        android:text="Test "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list_test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Check out [this article](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/297) for further information on layout weights.

Also, I would remove the `ScrollView` altogether. `ListView` manages scrolling itself, and you will run in to all kinds of problems if you embed it inside a container which handles scrolling. If you want to scroll `@is/tv_test` along with your `ListView` content, then consider putting it inside your `ListView` as a header. If you want it to remain static when the `ListView` scrolls, then keep it outside the `ListView`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you shouldn't have a listview inside a scrollview. Was making a few things wonky for me this morning